# Reactjs - How can I loop through an API that has been chained using axios?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

I am trying to build something with hacker news API but I have a problem though. To get the items displayed to the screen. The items I need I need to first call another endpoint. I called this endpoint and looped through it so I can pass the data from that endpoint to the items endpoint which I need to work but I am only getting one Item displayed. How can I further do this to get like 30 items all at once?

```
state={
    hackernews: []
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    Axios.get('/newstories.json')
    .then(res => {
      for(let i = 0; i<res.data.length; i++){
        const newsID = res.data[i];
        return Axios.get(`/item/${newsID}.json`)
      }
    })
    .then(res=>{
      const news = res.data
      this.setState({hackernews: [...this.state.hackernews, news]})
      
    })
  }
```

The hackernews api link https://github.com/HackerNews/API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `async/await` to fetch the IDs, then use `.then` normally :

```
 async componentDidMount(){
   let res=await Axios.get('/newstories.json')

     for(let i = 0; i<res.data.length; i++){
        const newsID = res.data[i];
       Axios.get(`/item/${newsID}.json`)  
       .then(res1=>{
          const news = res1.data
          this.setState({hackernews: [...this.state.hackernews, news]})
      
         })
     }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. However, there's a problem though. It comes onto the screen but throws an error.

Comment: It continues looping through the items until it throws an error of null for what I am trying to do. I have used the params method to limit it but it still throws it. I would look for more information online.

Comment: if there's a lot of details you could post another question